# Why can my node not be found

Tags: 7, nodes

I've created node with the following php code and I'm getting the error "The requested page "/node/xx" could not be found where xx is the nid.

```
//Code to add a new pmissue to the drupal7 database
$tmpTitle = "A test PM Issue Insert";
$tmpDescription = "<p>A test PM Issue Body Insertion</p>";
$tmpCallID = '002';
$InsTime = time();
$tmpTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $InsTime);

$result = db_query("SELECT field_callid_value FROM field_data_field_callid WHERE field_callid_value='$tmpCallID'");
$num_rows = $result->rowCount();
db_close();

if ($num_rows < 1) {

//Create new node
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO node (type, title, uid, status, comment, created, changed, language) VALUES ('pmissue', '$tmpTitle', 1, 1, 2, $InsTime , $InsTime, 'und')");

//Assign the new Node ID to $tmpNID
$tmpNID = db_query("SELECT nid FROM node WHERE created = $InsTime")->fetchField();

//set node VID to NID
$result = db_query("update node set vid='$tmpNID' where nid='$tmpNID'");

//Create Node Revision Record
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `node_revision` (`nid`, `vid`, `uid`, `title`, `log`, `timestamp`, `status`, `comment`, `promote`, `sticky`) VALUES ('$tmpNID', '92', '1', 'A test PM Issue ', '', '$InsTime', '1', '2', '1', '0')"); 

//Create comment count record
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `node_comment_statistics` (`nid`, `cid`, `last_comment_timestamp`, `last_comment_name`, `last_comment_uid`, `comment_count`) VALUES ('$tmpNID', '0', '$InsTime', NULL, '1', '0')"); 

//Insert Tracker_node record
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `tracker_node` (`nid`, `published`, `changed`) VALUES ('$tmpNID', '1', '$InsTime')"); 


//assign permissions to NODE (there are 9 of this to execute)
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `node_access` (`nid`, `gid`, `realm`, `grant_view`, `grant_update`, `grant_delete`) VALUES ('$tmpNID', '0', 'pmpermission_pmissue_update_all', '0', '1', '0')"); 
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `node_access` (`nid`, `gid`, `realm`, `grant_view`, `grant_update`, `grant_delete`) VALUES ('$tmpNID', '1', 'pmpermission_pmissue_update_own', '0', '1', '0')");
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `node_access` (`nid`, `gid`, `realm`, `grant_view`, `grant_update`, `grant_delete`) VALUES ('$tmpNID', '56', 'pmpermission_pmissue_update_belonged_organization', '0', '1', '0')");
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `node_access` (`nid`, `gid`, `realm`, `grant_view`, `grant_update`, `grant_delete`) VALUES ('$tmpNID', '0', 'pmpermission_pmissue_delete_all', '0', '0', '1')"); 
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `node_access` (`nid`, `gid`, `realm`, `grant_view`, `grant_update`, `grant_delete`) VALUES ('$tmpNID', '1', 'pmpermission_pmissue_delete_own', '0', '0', '1')");
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `node_access` (`nid`, `gid`, `realm`, `grant_view`, `grant_update`, `grant_delete`) VALUES ('$tmpNID', '56', 'pmpermission_pmissue_delete_belonged_organization', '0', '0', '1')");
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `node_access` (`nid`, `gid`, `realm`, `grant_view`, `grant_update`, `grant_delete`) VALUES ('$tmpNID', '0', 'pmpermission_pmissue_view_all', '1', '0', '0')"); 
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `node_access` (`nid`, `gid`, `realm`, `grant_view`, `grant_update`, `grant_delete`) VALUES ('$tmpNID', '1', 'pmpermission_pmissue_view_own', '1', '0', '0')");
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `node_access` (`nid`, `gid`, `realm`, `grant_view`, `grant_update`, `grant_delete`) VALUES ('$tmpNID', '56', 'pmpermission_pmissue_view_belonged_organization', '1', '0', '0')");


//Create body data
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO field_data_body (entity_type, bundle, entity_id, revision_id, body_value, body_format, delta, language, body_summary) VALUES ('node', 'pmissue', $tmpNID, $tmpNID, '$tmpDescription', 'full_html', 0, 'und', '')");

//Create body revision data
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `field_revision_body` (`entity_type`, `bundle`, `deleted`, `entity_id`, `revision_id`, `language`, `delta`, `body_value`, `body_summary`, `body_format`) VALUES ('node', 'pmissue', '0', '$tmpNID', '$tmpNID', 'und', '0', '$tmpDescription', '', 'full_html')"); 

//Create CallID field data
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO field_data_field_callid (entity_type, bundle, deleted, entity_id, revision_id, field_callid_value, delta, language) VALUES ('node', 'pmissue', 0, $tmpNID, $tmpNID, '$tmpCallID', 0, 'und')");

//Create pm category reference
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO field_data_pm_category (entity_type, bundle, entity_id, revision_id, pm_category_value, delta, language) VALUES ('node', 'pmissue', $tmpNID, $tmpNID, 'Support', 0, 'und')");

//Create CallID revision data
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `field_revision_pm_category` (`entity_type`, `bundle`, `deleted`, `entity_id`, `revision_id`, `language`, `delta`, `pm_category_value`) VALUES ('node', 'pmissue', '0', '$tmpNID', '$tmpNID', 'und', '0', 'support')"); 

//Create pm date reference
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO field_data_pm_date (entity_type, bundle, entity_id, revision_id, pm_date_value, pm_date_value2, delta, language) VALUES ('node', 'pmissue', $tmpNID, $tmpNID, '$tmpTime', '$tmpTime', 0, 'und')");

//Add revision date record
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `field_revision_pm_date` (`entity_type`, `bundle`, `deleted`, `entity_id`, `revision_id`, `language`, `delta`, `pm_date_value`, `pm_date_value2`) VALUES ('node', 'pmissue', '0', '$tmpNID', '$tmpNID', 'und', '0', '$tmpTime', '$tmpTime')"); 

//Create pm status reference
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO field_data_pm_status (entity_type, bundle, entity_id, revision_id, pm_status_value, delta, language) VALUES ('node', 'pmissue', $tmpNID, $tmpNID, 'inserted', 0, 'und')");

print $tmpNID;
} else {
print "CallID " . $tmpCallID . " already exists";
}
```

Comment: Check @mradcliffe's answer below, your problem will disappear if you follow his advice!

Answer (score 4):

You should follow [Drupal 7 - Create a Node in Code](https://www.drupal.org/node/1388922) to properly create a node programmatically.

1. Create an object of StdClass, and populate its properties with the required properties for a node per the documentation page.
2. Call `node_submit()` and `node_save()` to handle all necessary database operations for you.